# What Bur Dubai or Deira attractions open on Friday mornings?

Tags: sightseeing, dubai, recommendations, opening-hours

As the Dubai Metro [starts operating only at 1 p.m. on Fridays](http://metro.rtaprojects.me/index.php?action=planning_4), can someone please tell me what attractions (say, under AED 30) accessible by foot or abra from Deira open before that in January 2014?

Comment: Though the Dubai Mall and Burj Khalifa are open, walking 10 km to it is perhaps out of the question...

Comment: What is "abra" where you say "accessible by foot or abra"? Some kind of bus?

Comment: Sounds like a [Water Taxi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abra_(boat))

Answer (score 4):

According to these pages: [Tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g295424-i872-k5938917-Things_to_do_in_Dubai_on_Friday_morning-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai.html) and [Lonely Planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2054429), some open places are:

1. Dhow Wharfage - Open to the public 24x7
2. An [abra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abra_%28boat%29) ride on the creek for 1 dirham
3. Shops in Bur Dubai (Al Fahidi Street) are open for business until 11 a.m.

Additionally, the [Route 8 bus runs along the coast to Jebel Ali](http://www.evento.ae/RTA_BUS_Arabic/PDFS/Local%20Route%202011/Map%20for%20Route%208.pdf) taking [1 hour from end to end, from 5:30 a.m.](http://wojhati.rta.ae/dub/TTB/JP-LIVE-2_00006e7b.pdf)